# Refactoring a memory numbers game in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning React by doing simple games.

I'm doing a memory game which is, for the most part, finished and I'm not sure how I should refactor the code to be better.

The user task is basically to remember the numbers flashed, and then click them, until the user can't hold them in memory anymore.

How should I divide/refactor the code?

Also, how would you go forward with games like this? Would you perhaps create a gameEngine or such? Although this would be the part of refactoring right. I'm using React for games because I am learning React and improving it.

Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Cell from './sub-components/Cell/Cell';

import './styles.scss';


function BoardScene() {

    const [gameNumbers, setGameNumbers] = useState([]);
    const [isPlayerTurn, setIsPlayerTurn] = useState(false);

    const [currentScore, setCurrentScore] = useState(0);
    const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(0);

    const [flashCard, setFlashCard] = useState(null);
    const [clickedNumber, setClickedNumber] = useState(null);
    const [currentUserIndex, setCurrentUserIndex] = useState(0)


    function startGame() {
        addNewNumber()
    }

    function resetGame() {
        setGameNumbers([])
        setCurrentUserIndex(0)
        if (bestScore < gameNumbers.length) return setBestScore(gameNumbers.length)
    }


    const blinkCell = () => {
        let count = 0;

        setIsPlayerTurn(false);
        const timerID = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Inside interval before if")
            console.log("currentUserIndex", count, gameNumbers.length)

            if (count === gameNumbers.length) {
                setIsPlayerTurn(true);
                console.log("Inside time out if statement")
                clearInterval(timerID);
                count = 0;
                setFlashCard(null);
            } else {
                setFlashCard(gameNumbers[count]);
                count++;
            }

        }, 500);
    };

    function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    function addNewNumber() {
        console.log("Add new number")
        let memoryNumber = generateRandomNumber(1, 9)
        setGameNumbers(gameNumbers => [...gameNumbers, memoryNumber])
    }

    function clickedNumberHandle(number) {
        console.log("Clicked number", number)
        setClickedNumber(number)
        isMatch(number)
    }

    function isMatch(number) {
        if (number === gameNumbers[currentUserIndex]) {
            console.log("Correct")

            if (currentUserIndex + 1 === gameNumbers.length) {
                setCurrentUserIndex(0)
                console.log("set current index 0")
                addNewNumber()
                blinkCell();
            } else {
                console.log("set current index + 1")
                setCurrentUserIndex(currentUserIndex + 1)
            }

        } else {
            resetGame()
            console.log("game over")
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        blinkCell()
        console.log("Use effect start blinkCell")
    }, [gameNumbers])

    return (
        <>
            <div className="game-container">

                <div className="testing-stuff">
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={startGame}>Start Game</button>
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={addNewNumber}>
                        <button>Add new number</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Game numbers: </span>
                        {gameNumbers.map((item, i) => {
                            return <span key={i}>{item}</span>
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>User Turn: {isPlayerTurn ? "True" : "False"}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Score: {gameNumbers.length}</span>
                    </div>

                </div>



                <div className="board">
                    {Array(9).fill().map((x, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Cell key={i} onClick={() => clickedNumberHandle(i + 1)} number={i + 1} active={i + 1 === flashCard ? true : false} />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>

                <div className="stats">
                    <div className="stats__score-wrap">
                        <span>Score: </span><span>{gameNumbers.length}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="stats__bestScore-wrap">
                        <span>Best Score: </span><span>{bestScore}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default BoardScene;
```

GitHub Code: https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/memory-numbers-game/blob/e177dfdaafe5daf393f1ae8fcee0827a16474e8f/src/scenes/BoardScene/BoardScene.js

Live Game: https://memory-numbers-game.netlify.app/

Comment: Questions which are literally just "how do i refactor these 150 lines of code" and nothing more than that aren't really the questions Stack Overflow was designed for. SO is meant to help with *specific* debugging problems. If you want more general help, like questions around optimization or architecture, try the software engineering stack exchange

Comment: Fair enough. I was on stack exchange and they told me to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I would personally re-factor to use ES6 syntax for all your functions. At the moment some of them are using arrow functions and some aren't.

I'd also personally have functions that are performing generic actions you might want to use across your codebase (such as generateRandomNumber) in their own modules.

On a specific point that isn't an opinion. I would not use the index (i) of your array as a key. This can lead to many issues. I would look into using a library like [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate these keys.

Other than that looks again, and again I'm no expert. If you want some more info from someone who is I'd recommend [Kent C Dodd blog](https://kentcdodds.com/) and [Ben Awads Youtube channel.](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-8QAzbLcRglXeN_MY9blyw)